# Stacking Cables on Cisco 3750G Switch

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

I stacked two 3750G Cisco switches a few weeks ago, all go. But, yesterday I installed a 2nd stacking cable as well for full optimization. However, it is not registering it seems.

```
Cisco3750#sh switch stack-ports
  Switch #    Port 1       Port 2 
  --------    ------       ------ 
    1           Ok          Down  
    2           Ok          Down
```

I did a little Googling, found these two. Is this the correct way to enable the 2nd stacking cable?

```
switch 1 stack port 2 enable
switch 2 stack port 2 enable
```

EDIT 4PM:
Another search says to cross the cables (crisscross). Not sure what's up here, but the above commands to enable did not cut it.

```
Each 3750 switch’s back has two stack ports 1 and 2.

Suppose you want to connect two switches with two stack cables:

1st switch port 1 connects to 2nd switch port 2.

1st switch port 2 connects to 1st switch port 1.

The stack cables will be crossed.
```

UPDATE #2 10:30PM

Powered off, looped stacking cables as suggested, powered on. Shows the loop (port 1 to port 2, vice versa) but 2nd cable still not registering.

```
Cisco3750#switch 1 stack port 2 enable
Enabling/disabling a stack port may cause undesired stack changes. Continue?[confirm]
Cisco3750#switch 2 stack port 2 enable
Enabling/disabling a stack port may cause undesired stack changes. Continue?[confirm]

Cisco3750#show switch stack-ring speed

Stack Ring Speed        : 16G
Stack Ring Configuration: Half
Stack Ring Protocol     : StackWise

Cisco3750#sh switch stack-ports       
  Switch #    Port 1       Port 2 
  --------    ------       ------ 
    1           Ok          Down  
    2          Down          Ok
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying it. Why are you asking here if you haven't already?

Comment: Why? Because I'm asking if it's the correct way, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You do that to create a loop. When you stack more than two switches, it is important to do that so that any single cable loss doesn't isolate switches. With a loop, the loss of a single link still leaves all switches connected.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a stack of switches, you want to create a loop with the stacking cables. Port 2 on one switch connects to port 1 on the next switch. Continue that until the last switch which will connect back to the first switch.

This creates a loop in the switch connections. When you lose one link in the loop, you will still have a continuous link between all the switches. Without a loop, you will end up with two groups of switches isolated from each other.

This is a picture of how you should connect. It is for 3750X switches, but the stacking principle is the same for all the stacking switches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ron Maupin. So this applies even if the stack is just 2 switches? If I do this, I assume my output will show both ports on and full 32G?

Comment: You don't double the bandwidth, you gain redundancy. Since each switch comes with a StackWise cable, you get it for free. If you have more than three switches, and you use horizontal cable management (recommended), you will probably need to get one of the longer cables.

Comment: Ok confused. Right now they're stacked 2 switches, 16G stack ring speed and half stack ring config. I was told a 2nd cable would make it a full 32G? http://imgur.com/a1ygvSP @RonMaupin

Comment: Not that I have heard of. Cisco has a paper about the StackWise technology [Cisco StackWise and StackWise Plus Technology](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/prod_white_paper09186a00801b096a.html).

Comment: thank you. It does say 32G but I'll give it a shot and see.

Comment: @Cazzette, I see your confusion. You get 16 Gb each direction, so you could call it 32 Gb, but I really wouldn't. It's like the confusion that used to exist about full duplex since you could get 100 Mb each direction, some vendors called that 200 Mb.

Comment: ok what would be my benefit in hooking up the second cable then? Now I'm a bit confused. The first cable basically stacked the two switches and also made it convenient to manage both through the first switch. My assumption and understanding was the second cable will bring the speed on both switches to the full capacity.

Comment: Besides the obvious that you have stated, a stack looks like a single switch, the real gain is redundancy, you eliminate the problem of one link failing and separating the switches. If you use an uplink off both switches, or you connect a server to both switches, you can actually port channel between the switches, and a failure of one link will not mess that up. This is something we do all the time since the users and server guys are paranoid about redundancy. StackWise fails over almost instantaneously, and port channels fail over much, much faster than STP or even routing protocols.

Comment: didn't work (loop method), I edited my first post with output. Did the loop, powered back on (cycle). 2nd cable won't kick in for some reason.

Comment: Try from the master (switch 1?) port 2 to the second switch port 1. Basically, the opposite of what you have. All the documentation I have seen says to use the 2nd port from the master to the next switch. I'm not sure why it would matter, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did. My original way was port 1 to port 1, port 2 to port 2. On the 2nd switch, I simply swapped them so it's port 1 to port 2, port 2 to port 1. Rebooted (2nd switch only), no go.

Comment: You have something wrong with the cable or something. We do this all the time, and I'm reviewing the document we have for stacking the switches. I guess you could try to bring the stack up with only switch1, port 2 connected to switch 2. port 1 to see if that works.